# How to increment a variable within a for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, google-sheets, yahoo-finance

Im building a google sheet to keep track of stock prices for the stocks i own. I have an API running thats connected to Google Sheets and my own python application.

My google sheet looks like this

```
Stock | Previous close

AAPL  | 316.73

NVDA  | 348.71

SPOT  | 191.00
```

i currently have the code running as follows.

```
import requests 
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials 

sheet = client.open("Stock").sheet1
AAPL = sheet.cell(2,1).value
url = ('https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+AAPL+'?p='+AAPL+'&.tsrc=fin-srch')
response = requests.get(url) 
htmltext = response.text
splitlist = htmltext.split("Previous Close")
afterfirstsplit =splitlist[1].split("\">")[2]
aftersecondsplit = afterfirstsplit.split("</span>")
datavalue = aftersecondsplit[0] 
sheet.update_cell(2,2,datavalue)
```

# this would update the value within my google sheet to the previous close price

For each individual stock, i would copy and paste, change the stock symbol, to find the value of the next quote. 
I know theres a way to use FOR statements to automate this process. I tried that with the following but it wouldnt update as needed. I reached a wall at this point and would appreciate any help or insight on how i could automate this function.

```
tickers = {sheet.cell(2,1).value : [],
           sheet.cell(3,1).value : [],
           sheet.cell(4,1).value : [], 
           sheet.cell(5,1).value :[]}

for symbols in tickers: 

    url = ('https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+symbols+'?p='+symbols+'&.tsrc=fin-srch')
    response = requests.get(url) 
    htmltext = response.text
    splitlist = htmltext.split("Previous Close")
    afterfirstsplit =splitlist[1].split("\">")[2]
    aftersecondsplit = afterfirstsplit.split("</span>")
    datavalue = aftersecondsplit[0]
    sheet.update.cell(2,1,datavalue)
    print (datavalue)
```

Doing this gathers all the values of the current stock prices and it does import it into the excel file but only to one coordinate. I dont know how to increase the '1' within sheet.update.cell(2,1,datavalue), each time within the FOR statement. I believe that is the way to solve this, but if anyone has any other suggestions, im all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to answering this part of your question:

**"I don't know how to increase the '1' within sheet.update.cell(2,1,datavalue), each time within the FOR statement."**

This is how you increment a counter inside a for loop typically speaking:

```
counter = 1

for symbol in tickers:
    #Your code
    sheet.update.cell(2,counter,datavalue)
    counter = counter+1
```

Comment: Thanks Akib! That was it. I referenced the wrong value there, should have been the "2" and not the "1". The code works! thanks!

Comment: No worries, I am going to suggest an edit to the question name as "How to increment a variable within a for loop in python", and it might eventually be closed cause I have a feeling duplicates might already exist. I am personally not going to flag it tough @VanguardCoder

Answer (score 1):

While counter variables are a very common pattern used in most programming language (see [Akib Rhast's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62033132/python-finance-and-google-sheets#62033208)), the more pythonic way to do it is by using the [`enumerate` builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```py
for column, symbol in enumerate(tickers, start=1):
    # do stuff
    sheet.update.cell(2,column,datavalue)
```

#### what is `enumerate`?

As the documentation states, `enumerate` takes something that you can iterate on (like a list) and returns a tuple with the counter as the first element and the elements from the iterator as the second element:

```py
seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
list(enumerate(seasons, start=1))
# outputs [(1, 'Spring'), (2, 'Summer'), (3, 'Fall'), (4, 'Winter')]
```

It also has the advantage of doing so in a memory-efficient manner and is directly tied to your loop.

### why is there a comma in my `for` loop?

This is just syntactic sugar in python that allows you to unpack a tuple or list:

```
alist = [1, 2, 3]
first, second, third = alist
print(third) # outputs 3
print(second) # outputs 2
print(first) # outputs 1
```

As `enumerate` returns a tuple, you are basically assigning each element on that tuple to a different variable at the same time.